# remove files remotely using c# and system.io.file

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I am trying to remove a file located at a remote server named tn1pfe-01. But an exception is returned instead.

> The given path's format is not supported

Here is my instruction:

`File.Delete(@"\\"+"tn1pfe-01"+@"\"+"C:\\Users\\skobbi\\Documents\\Fiddler2\\sa.txt" );`

Comment: that's because it's not a valid path. \\server\c:\doesnt\work set up a share?

Comment: That path doesn't look correct. Have you tried `File.Exists(path)`?

Comment: It is solved now, the path was invalid. Thanks stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

When you access a remote machine you cannot refer to the drive as `C:\\`. Instead you need to use the hidden administrative share `c$`, e.g.

> \svr\c$\Windows\file.txt

So in your case, you will need

```
File.Delete(@"\\"+"tn1pfe-01"+@"\"+"c$\\Users\\skobbi\\Documents\\Fiddler2\\sa.txt");
```

If the file path if a variable containing a local path, you can generate this by replacing `:\` with `$\`:

```
string localPath = "c:\\Users\\skobbi\\Documents\\Fiddler2\\sa.txt";
File.Delete(@"\\" + "tn1pfe-01" + @"\" + localPath.Replace(@":\", @"$\"));
```